# How to dynamically expend Angular website?

Tags: php, html, angular, content-management-system, expand

I'm building a website with Angular.

I want to add duplicates for a template HTML page when clicking a button in a management system.

Here is a simplified example.

Let's say, I have a html page **template.html** with an image tag. I want to click on a button in another html page **manager.html** This action asks for a new image source string and then duplicates the template.html file, gives it a proper name and set's the image tag with the correct source string.
The newly created html page should now be accessible using the correct url and html page name.

This is probably possible with php but can it be done with the Angular platform?

Comment: Why do you want to create a new html page? Creating a physical HTML file is not possible with Angular

Comment: Are you asking about router params:https://angular.io/guide/router#accessing-query-parameters-and-fragments? or  simple about `*ngFor`https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#inside-ngfor ? or use `ComponentFactoryResolver` to add a component declared in `entryComponents`?

Answer (score 0):

> You need to create `dynamic component` to achieve this. Then by using of dynamic component selector along with some `@Input and @Output` decorator you can use same html for other purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see.
Kind of new to Angular and more advanced website programming.

I managed to setup a back-end with mongoDB and mongoose to add users to it using an Angular front-end. When a user logs in I load his/her data into a template html file.

Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ivan said, it is impossible to manipulate something in a file on the server while the angular app is running on client machine.